# Server do not response to multiple request from one client

Tags: python, sockets

I try to implement a server which only responds to one client at a time and client side. For the client side, I only used one connection and can send multiple requests to server. For the first request, everything goes well. For all the requests after the first one, the client will report error: `socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`
. I post my server and client code along with the sample test below:

The server part:

```
import socket
import re
#create server socket. AF_INET-> ipv4. SOCK_STREAM->socket type
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 20000
#bind the socket to localhost and a well-know port
serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), port))
serverSocket.listen(3)

while True:
    clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    request = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print('Server received', repr(request))
    splitRequest = re.split('\<|\>', request)
    if splitRequest[0] == 'EXIT':
        if len(splitRequest) == 1:
            print "Normal exit"
        elif len(splitRequest) > 1:
            print splitRequest[1]
    else:
        if splitRequest[0] == 'GET':
            fileName = splitRequest[1]
            path = 'test_files/' + fileName
            try :
                with open(path, 'r') as serverFile:
                    message = serverFile.read()
                    print message
                    clientSocket.send(message)
            except Exception as e:
                message = str(e)
                print message
                clientSocket.send(message)
        elif splitRequest[0] == 'BOUNCE':
            message = splitRequest[1]
            print message
            clientSocket.sendall(message)
    clientSocket.close()
```

The client side:

```
import socket
import re
def isValidRequest(input):
    if re.match('GET\<.+\>', input) or re.match('BOUNCE\<.+\>', input) or input == 'EXIT' or re.match('EXIT\<.+\>', input):
        return True
    return False
def receiveAll(socket):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096  # 4 KiB
    data = ""
    while True:
        part = socket.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        data += part
        if len(part) < BUFF_SIZE:
            # either 0 or end of data
            break
    return data


# create a client socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()
# port number
port = 20000
# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    request = raw_input()
    if isValidRequest(request):
        if request == 'EXIT' or re.match('EXIT\<.+\>', request):
            s.send(request)
            break
        else:
            s.send(request)
            print "after send"
            content = receiveAll(s)

            print content
    else:
        print "Invalid request, please enter it again!"
# close client connection
s.close()
```

I run a test for request the same txt file-"MACD.txt" from server twice. The input in the console is "GET".The print message in the console for client:

```
*GET<MACD.txt>*
after send
MACD, short for moving average convergence/divergence, is a trading indicator used in technical analysis of stock prices, created by Gerald Appel in the late 1970s.[1] It is supposed to reveal changes in the strength, direction, momentum, and duration of a trend in a stock's price.
*GET<MACD.txt>*
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
after send
```

The print message in the server part. And you can see server only print message for the first request:

```
Got a connection from ('192.168.126.1', 60567)
('Server received', "u'GET<MACD.txt>'")
MACD, short for moving average convergence/divergence, is a trading indicator used in technical analysis of stock prices, created by Gerald Appel in the late 1970s.[1] It is supposed to reveal changes in the strength, direction, momentum, and duration of a trend in a stock's price.
```

I am confused by what I saw since I search the same problem in Stackoverflow and none of them match my case. I also read the document for python socket but still got nothing

Comment: You're closing the client socket on the server. That means you have to do `s.connect((host, port))` in each iteration of your loop, not just once. (You might have to create a new socket altogether, I'm not sure.)`

Comment: @Rawing I think it is not the case. I close the socket after the loop. That is how to make sure I only use one connection for one client rather than open a connection for each request